# Most compatible RAW format for Linux users?

Tags: raw, linux, rawtherapee

After looking at various APS-C and full-frame mirrorless cameras, I thought I had settled on the Canon M200, because its size and image quality are great.

Then however I got some sample RAWs and to my surprise the CR3 file format is not compatible with any program that runs on Linux e.g. dcraw or rawtherapee.

Can anyone suggest a mirrorless camera whose RAWs are easily readable on Linux?

Comment: Check for ART package: https://bitbucket.org/agriggio/art/wiki/Home (RawTherapee derivate with CR3 support)

Comment: The DNG format is well-documented and specified, the compatibility is very good

Comment: Just be aware that some parts of the *maker notes* section of the EXIF info for many raw formats (including all of Canon's raw file formats) are stripped when converted to DNG. If all you ever use are raw converters that don't leverage this information (Adobe products, for instance and most open source Linux raw convertors), then you shouldn't care. But if you later change your mind and want to use a raw convertor that does use this information, you'll need to have the original .cr*x* files to access that proprietary information included in the metadata.

Answer (score 4):

It takes some time for developers to support raw files from new cameras, even though they may share the same file extension as raw files from previous cameras.

Many Linux raw processing programs use `libraw`. Here is the list of [officially supported cameras](https://www.libraw.org/supported-cameras). A number of cameras on the list do use the `cr3` extension, including the Canon EOS M200.

Unless you compile from source, you may need to wait for distro repositories to be updated. Many popular distros are updated at six month intervals.

Comment: Note though, that neither RawTherapee nor darktable use libraw, at least as a shared library. In fact, darktable doesn't even use libraw at all, instead linking to librawspeed that it contains in the source tree. And RawTherapee contains some pieces of libraw in its sources, but not the library verbatim. So, installing an updated version of libraw won't help in any case with these two programs.

Comment: @Ruslan Supported cameras would correspond to the version of `libraw` used in each release.  The consequence for end users is longer wait times for updates to be pulled from `libraw`.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked at a time when CR3 was not yet supported in darktable. [It has been supported since 3.8.0.](https://www.darktable.org/2021/12/darktable-3.8.0-released/)

A more general answer to this question is that there is an [automatically generated list of cameras supported by darktable](https://www.darktable.org/resources/camera-support/) on its website, in which any camera can be looked up. The M200 mentioned in the question is now supported for example.